# Can UIWebView catche the event caused by pressing the MediaPlayer's done button

Tags: ios, delegates, uiwebview, media-player

I want to use `UIWebView` to load URL and play vedios. When I press done button in MediaPlayer control on the `UIWebView`, I want to do something.
My Question is, in this case can it be OK, or does the `UIWwebView` has a delegate method to do after pressing done button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Done" button only shows up in full screen mode.  You can detect the end of full screen mode by observing the `@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"` mode:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:)
        name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"
        object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)moviePlayerDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // This is where you do whatever you want because the user pressed "Done".
}
```

The `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification` is not documented, so I don't know if it will pass App Store review.  If you're not planning to distribute via the App Store, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Did you distribute your app via App Store? Did it pass?